# While selecting video from gallery giving Invalid column latitude error in Android 10 pixel 2

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-10.0

```
>select video from gallery
     Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,      
     android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);


>getting error in below line
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

--------- beginning of crash

```
2019-11-18 17:28:44.745 12653-12653/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.parsaniahardik.selectvideogallerycamera, PID: 12653
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content://media/external/video/media/727/ORIGINAL/NONE/1667935740 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F727/ORIGINAL/NONE/1667935740} }} to activity {com.example.parsaniahardik.selectvideogallerycamera/com.example.parsaniahardik.selectvideogallerycamera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:155)
    at com.example.parsaniahardik.selectvideogallerycamera.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:98)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

2019-11-18 17:28:44.751 12653-12653/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12653 SIG: 9

Comment: please describe the issue in more details, and maybe post the full stacktrace

Comment: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F727/ORIGINAL/NONE/113623020


this is uri of selected video from gallery. 
Getting crash on    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null); line

Comment: please update your question description above, add the code you're using to fetch the video and the code you use to handle the response

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped#photos-location-info

Comment: @Vaibhavi is it possible you copy/pasted the wrong stacktrace? I don't see anything in there about invalid column.

Comment: @Vaibhavi Did you find out why this is happening?

Comment: Is this issue resolved? can you please update answer.

Comment: I also faced the same issue. Check my solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586124/illegalargumentexception-invalid-column-latitude/65776020#65776020

Answer (score 1):

Please use this **Util** class for getting the generated Media path-

```
   public class Util {
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri){
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if(isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context,uri)){
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme()))
        {
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String getDataColumn(@NonNull Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isMediaDocument(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

}
```

And for calling ->

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setTypeAndNormalize("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),  GALLERY);
```

Comment: I also faced the same issue. Check my solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586124/illegalargumentexception-invalid-column-latitude/65776020#65776020