# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column latitude

Tags: java, android

Following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info#RetrieveFileInfo)
 I tried querying `ContentResolver` to get the file size, like this:

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == video_request_code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()){
                    if (uri.getScheme() != null){
                        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
                            int sizeIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                            Log.e("size", ""+cur.getLong(sizeIndex));
                        }else if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
                            File ff = new File(uri.getPath());
                            Log.e("size", ""+ff.length());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (cur != null)
                    cur.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column latitude
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column latitude
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:423)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:944)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:880)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:836)
        at com.my.package.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:146)
        ...
```

The crash is pointing to `Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);`, but as you can see, I'm not querying the latitude column. In fact, at the time of the crash, I have not queried any column.

I could only reproduce this when selecting a file from Google Photo on a device running Android 10.

---

My Question:

Why is this happening and how can I overcome it?

---

Edit:

I tried passing the projection of the columns. To test, I passed the following:

```java
String[] projection = {OpenableColumns.SIZE, OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: Try using an actual projection (`String[]` of "columns" to return), rather than passing in `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried this, please see my edit.

Comment: Hmmmm... that is very strange. It feels like Google Photo is automatically adding `latitude` to your projection, then is crashing because you can't have that column on Android 10. I suspect that there is little that you can do about this, other than see if there is a place to file a bug for Google Photo.

Comment: same problem occured in Api 29 emulator. Not on my xiaomi device with android 10 and api 30 emulator

Comment: I did open an issue on issuetracker and this should be fixed according to Google - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155579897

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in Android 10+. This issue is due to scoped storage which is introduced in Android 10.

**Solutions:**
My solution to this problem is to create an input stream from a Uri. Check the code snippet below.

```
fun getVideoRealPath(
        context: Context, uri: Uri
    ): File? {
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver ?: return null

        // Create file path inside app's data dir
        val filePath = (context.applicationInfo.dataDir + File.separator
                + System.currentTimeMillis())
        val file = File(filePath)
        try {
            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) ?: return null
            val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            val buf = ByteArray(1024)
            var len: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) outputStream.write(buf, 0, len)
            outputStream.close()
            inputStream.close()
        } catch (ignore: IOException) {
            return null
        }
        return file
    }
```

Comment: This is not a solution, it's a workaround. You are writing the file to your applications directory instead of querying the `Uri` returned from media store.

Comment: how to get file extension from uri

Answer (score -3):

I found the solution

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

When I use this, it shows the issue.

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
galleryIntent.setType("video/*");
galleryIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
galleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

This works well and you will get the size and temporary file path.

Consult these links.

https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/95b9ba77181b627c8dd1c27369b21a3c69dc4a3d/android/src/main/java/com/reactnative/ivpusic/imagepicker/PickerModule.java#L369

https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactnative/ivpusic/imagepicker/RealPathUtil.java

Finger crossed.