# Android 10 : Crashing When selecting video in android Q

Tags: android, onactivityresult, android-contentresolver, android-10.0

I want to upload a video from gallery. I use `startActivityForResualt` and get data from

```
onActivityResualt
```

then pass uri to the method for get real path this is my method :

```
private static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri uri) {

    final String column = "_data";
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null)) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image: this is my onActivityResualt]

**so it works on all API except android 10**. 
in android 10 it opens video picker activity and I can choose a video but when I choose the video and it wants to back to main activity crashes and show this error!!:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column latitude

and this is my log :

```
2020-05-26 20:39:53.736 6048-6705/com.google.android.apps.photos E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column latitude
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:423)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:944)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:880)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:836)
        at _1194.a(PG:97)
        at com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider.a(PG:32)
        at alca.query(PG:34)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1214)
        at alca.query(PG:10)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1307)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:267)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:104)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
2020-05-26 20:39:53.755 7315-7315/diar.neo.mainactivvity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: diar.neo.mainactivvity, PID: 7315
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content://media/external/video/media/30/ORIGINAL/NONE/893152725 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F30/ORIGINAL/NONE/893152725} }} to activity {diar.neo.mainactivvity/diar.neo.mainactivvity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column latitude
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

What do I do?

Comment: "so it works on all API except android 10" -- not reliably. There is no requirement for `DATA` to point to anything that your app can use. Just use the `Uri` directly (e.g., `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`).

Comment: you are getting the path of the file wrong

Comment: pass MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA to getColumnIndexOrThrow function instead of column.
`final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);`

Comment: it woks perfectly on all API bellow android Q

Comment: @mohosyny Are you testing on an emulator? If not, what device are you testing with?

Comment: yes, I tested on some emulators with android 10 and the result was the same

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: works on poco x3 nfc android 10. And emulator api 30. But not on emulator 29..!

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155579897

Answer (score 0):

I usually used to use this file to get the full path of anything from the Gallery.

Give it a shot and let me know.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/" + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME);
    Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

}
```

Comment: Did you test it on Android 10?

Comment: tested it a while ago on the emulator with an image and it worked.

Comment: thanks, but I tested it on the emulator too, and the same error on android 10

Comment: I updated the solution. Can you try with an image using the answer above and let us see what happens. This should work.

Comment: I didn't understand where should I use code above in my code

Comment: and i updated my question with a shot of using your soulotion

Comment: It crashes for video, not for image.

Comment: I also faced the same issue. Check my solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586124/illegalargumentexception-invalid-column-latitude/65776020#65776020